# airflow scheduler executes dag earlier than its start date

Tags: python-datetime, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I try to execute a dag on `start_date= datetime.strptime('3/2/2020 8:20:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')` and `schedule_interval=schedule_interval='20/5 8 * * *'` but dag get executed before the actual start_date.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

default_args = {
'owner':'admin',
'retries': 0,
'email_on_retry': False,
'depends_on_past': False,
'email_on_failure': False,
'priority_weight': 10,
'email': [''],
'queue':'bash_queue',
'start_date': datetime.strptime('3/2/2020 8:20:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'),
}

dag = DAG('somename',
default_args=default_args,
catchup = False,
schedule_interval='20/5 8 * * *'
 )
dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

can anyone help me to understand the odd behavior of airflow?

Comment: did you fix it?.

Comment: please have a look at [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html], it is explained there as well. If any query, do ask!